# Limitar casas decimais

Tags: android, python, decimal

Eu estou fazendo um programa simples que gera dois números aleatórios e pergunta ao usuário quanto é tal número +,-,/,* por outro número, e eu quero que tenham números decimais também, mas quando eu uso o `uniform()` ele gera muitas casas decimais, e eu não quero isso, eu quero limitar pra 3 casas. Mas eu preciso fazer isso direto na definição das variáveis, e isso eu não sei como, alguém sabe?

Código:

```
n1 = str(uniform(1,1000))
# gera um número float de 1 à 999.
    
n2 = str(uniform(1, 1000))
# gera um número float de 1 à 999.
```

*(Eu estou usando str para usar futuramente em um eval)*

Comment: Veja a biblioteca [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

Answer (score 3):

Faça assim, coloque a expressão `uniform(1, 1000)` dentro da função round.
Onde o parâmetro n é o número de casas decimais que você quer.
vai ficar assim:

```py
n1 = str(round(uniform(1, 1000), n))
n2 = str(round(uniform(1, 1000), n))
```

Comment: ```n1 = str(round(uniform(1, 1000), 3))
print(n1)``` as vezes funciona, as vezes não. Eu prefiria algo tipo ```:.3f```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode arredondar o valor para uma determinada precisão de dígitos decimais com [round()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#round) e formatar a saída como um [decimal de ponto fixo](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) com o número de casas decimais desejadas:

```
from random import uniform

def truncar(valor, casas):
    return f"{round(valor, casas):.{casas}f}"

print(truncar(uniform(1, 1000), 3))
```